# How do I print a saved search based sublist from a custom record using advanced PDF/HTML forms?

Tags: html, netsuite, freemarker

I have a custom record that has a custom saved search sublist that I cannot get to print using advance `pdf/html`. In the `WYSIWYG` mode there is no "`search`" section and when I try to print it using the `freemarker` syntax it is not working.

**Code below**

```
<#list record.customsublist72 as pricechange>
    ${pricechange.field1}, ${pricechange.field2}
</#list>
```

Thanks for any help, this is has been very difficult as I have very little `NetSuite` experience and less `HTML` experience.

Answer (score 1):

> As of now, there is no direct settings or sourcing of code to directly
>   call the records on a custom sublist.

https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/74751/kw/print%20sublist (Requires NS Login)

I've run into a similar scenario, and I believe you'll have to use Suitescript to accomplish this. But as of now, there doesn't seem to be a native method to print this way.